# is there pywebview Alternatives that depend on chrome and not on safari

Tags: javascript, css, django, qt, webview

Is there's any similar or alternatives to Pywebview: https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview
While it depends on the version of installed Safari on OS X and QT.
I am trying to make a desktop app out of Django project. but a lot of features (css & javascript) are not working well on Safari neither Pywebview, and works perfectly on chrome.
After that it will be all encapsulated with py2app.

Ps: Or, is there a way to make it depend on chrome.

I am using Pywebview as follow:

```
webview.create_window("AntikytheraERP", 
"http://localhost:9090/Departments/choose/",width=1000, height=600, 
resizable=True, fullscreen=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All recent versions of Qt ship with [QtWebEngine](https://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine), which is based on Chromium, the open source version of Chrome.

WebEngine can be used either as a [Qt widget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) or as a [QML component](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html).

Comment: I was reading the documentations and it seems a very effective way, but I couldn't find the proper way to use it with Django. I edited my post so you can have an idea about what I am doing exactly. Can you please show me how to use QtWebEngine?